# Can we make bagging equivalent to random forest if we take max features in our own defined decision tree and pass it as estimator?

Tags: random-forest, bagging

If  in bagging we defined our own tuned decision tree as estimator with max features as parameter in that estimator rather than taking by default decision tree estimator available in BaggingClassifer in sckit learn? Will this bagging  be equivalent to Random forest then?

dct= DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features=4,random_state=2021)

model_bg=BaggingRegressor(base_estimator=dct,random_state=2021,oob_score=True,max_features = X_train.shape[1],n_estimators=15,max_samples=X_train.shape[0])

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html):

> A Bagging classifier is an ensemble meta-estimator that fits base classifiers each on random subsets of the original dataset and then aggregate their individual predictions (either by voting or by averaging) to form a final prediction. […]
>
> **bootstrap: *bool*, default=True**
> Whether samples are drawn with replacement. If False, sampling without replacement is performed.
>
> **bootstrap_features: *bool*, default=False**
> Whether features are drawn with replacement.

Random forest *is* just a bagging classifier (or regressor) using trees as base classifiers. It by default resamples *both* rows (samples) and columns (features).

Notice that you *don't* want to use the same random seed for each tree, because you want the base classifiers to be randomly different. Other arguments like `max_depth` can be passed to random forest directly. Almost always you should just use the random forest, rather than constructing it yourself since the build-in implementation is already tested and optimized for the task.

Comment: hi that was max_features i want to wrote and not max_depth. I am new in ML. So do you mean it will act as a random forest however there is a ready made implementation of that so we dont create it by ourself? Please confirm

Comment: @RaufurKhan yes, this is what I'm saying. If you don't have very good reason to do so, do not re-invent the wheel, this usually backfires.

Comment: Thank you very much tim

Comment: @RaufurKhan if this answers your question, please mark it as "solved".